# Why do Haskell type signature declarations have multiple arrows?

Tags: haskell, syntax, types

Sorry this is worded poorly, but it's hard to describe.

I guess I'll just jump to the example:

```
add                     :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
add x y                 =  x + y
```

why is it:

```
:: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

instead of:

```
:: Integer, Integer -> Integer
```

the arrow is the "[Function type-mapping operator](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/~rolf/Edu/DM22/F06/haskell-operatorer.pdf)", not some kind of separator, no?

Comment: It might not be clear from the answers here, but also notice that `(->)` is just a regular type taking two parameters (albeit with a special case syntax, and hidden implementation). Fire up ghci and run `:info (->)`; you'll see there are even a few typeclass instances defined for `((->) a)` already in the Prelude

Comment: Note that in [Clean](http://wiki.clean.cs.ru.nl/Documentation), an otherwise very Haskell-like language, you can omit some of the arrows. So you can write `Int Int -> Int` for `Int -> Int -> Int`, or even (the to me unreadable) `(a b -> c) [a] [b] -> [c])` for  `((a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c])`.  The interpretation seems to [subtly different from the one found in Haskell](http://wiki.clean.cs.ru.nl/download/html_report/CleanRep.2.2_5.htm#_Toc311798010). If I understand it is able to express some distinctions we cannot make in Haskell.

Comment: http://www.imada.sdu.dk/~rolf/Edu/DM22/F06/haskell-operatorer.pdf

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because of currying.  Think about the type of this:

```
add 3 :: Integer -> Integer
```

If you give `add` one number it returns a function that maps an `Integer` to another integer.  So you could do this:

```
map (add 3) [1..10]
```

It doesn't make sense to treat arguments differently from return types with partial application.

**EDIT to clarify**

I think bheklilr makes a good point that the type signature can be read like this

```
add :: Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)
```

We can take a function with more arguments, `zipWith3` because it is the only one I can really think of.

```
zipWith3 :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [d]
```

If we just read what this does it takes a function that takes 3 values and returns a fourth and then 3 lists of those values respectively and it returns a list of the fourth value.  Trying it out.

```
add3 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
add3 a b c = a + b + c

Prelude>zipWith3 add3 [1] [2] [3]
[6]
```

Although, in this case all the values are of type `Int` it still demonstrates the point.

Now what if we don't give it all the lists? What if we give it no lists just `add3`.

```
zipWith3 add3 :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
zipWith3 add3 :: [Int] -> ([Int] -> [Int] -> [Int])
zipWith3 add3 :: [Int] -> [Int] -> ([Int] -> [Int])
```

So, now we have a function that takes 3 lists and returns a list.  But this is also a function that takes a list are returns a function that takes 2 lists and returns a list.  There is no way to distinguish between them really.

```
(zipWith3 add3) [1,2] [3,4] [5,6] :: [Int]
(zipWith3 add3) [1,2] :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

See where I'm going with this? There is no distinction between arguments are return types.

Comment: I'm getting pretty giddy learning Haskell, it is really not more of the same. I'm only 2 days in so thank you for tolerating the rookie question :)

Comment: I'm honestly still a little confused. I never defined a partial solution function. How is this implicitly defined? is it just built into the language to package up the function with one argument hard coded in and pass it along if given less args? what happens with three or 4 args?

Comment: @BretFontecchio check out my edit, hopefully that helps

Answer (score 16):

My "aha" moment was when I realised that

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

actually looks much more natural when you group explicitly:

```
map :: ( a -> b )
    -> ([a]->[b])
```

it *takes a function and returns a list-function*. With uncurried definition this grouping doesn't quite work, does it?

```
map :: ( a -> b
       ,[a])->[b]
```

yet this grouping is in a way a much "deeper", more useful way of thinking about the function. In particular, if you generalise it:

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a->b) -> f a->f b
```

A [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor_%28category_theory%29) does two things: takes some type (such as `a` or `b`) and associates it to another type (`f a`, `f b`). But it also takes a *morphism* (`a -> b`) and associates it to another morphism (`f a -> f b`).

Answer (score 8):

The type signature is more properly read as

```
add :: Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)
```

Which is very different from

```
add :: (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer
```

The first is denotes a function that takes an `Integer` and returns a new function that takes an `Integer` and returns an `Integer`.  This is to facilitate partial application of functions, so things like

```
(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int  -- specialized to Int

(1 +) :: Int -> Int

> map (1 +) [1..10]
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```