# Still confuse how type signature with multiple arrows work

Tags: haskell, currying, type-signature

I checked a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459981/why-do-haskell-type-signature-declarations-have-multiple-arrows) before and seems understand. I know

```
f :: a -> b -> c
```

is the curry form of

```
g :: (a, b) -> c
```

But as the type signature gets longer than 2 arrows, I feel confused again.

```
myscanr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]
myscanr op z [] = [z]
myscanr op z (x:xs) = op x (head qs) : qs
  where
    qs = myscanr op z xs
```

Are `(a -> b -> b)` and `[b]` the input and output? What are the rest in the middle then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well conceptually, a function in Haskell has always *exactly one* parameter. Indeed, in fact the signature:

```
myscanr :: (a ->  b -> b ) ->  b ->  [a] -> [b]
```

is short for:

```
myscanr :: (a -> (b -> b)) -> (b -> ([a] -> [b]))
```

So there is always *one* parameter, but the result can be a *function* as well, and we can then provide an argument for that function to obtain a value, or another result, so this is some sort of "chaining".

You could compare it to a programming language like Python where instead of having a function that accepts several parameters, it each time accepts a single parameter. For example:

```
# python

def add(x):
    def addx(y):
        return x + y
    return addx
```

So here we have a function `add`. We can call it with a single parameter `x`. If we do that, with for example `x=4`, then it will return another function (where `x` is scoped). It is only if we then call that function with a parameter (for example `y=3`), that we get the outcome, like:

```
>>> add(4)
<function add.<locals>.addx at 0x7f1c519e7b70>
>>> add(4)(3)
7
```

Well in Haskell, this model is the standard: every function accepts only a single parameter. But since that is the case, the syntax can be improved. Instead of having to write `((myscanr((+)))(0))([1, 4, 2, 5])`, we can write `myscanr (+) 0 [1, 4, 2, 5]`, and Haskell will automatically interpret this as a function call with `myscanr` as function and `(+)` as parameter, another function call with as function the result of the previous call and `0` as parameter, and then another function call with as function the outcome of the previous call with `[1, 4, 2, 5]` as parameter.

Since syntactically it looks a bit like we have made a call with *three* parameters, one could say that the `(a -> b -> b)`, `b` and `[a]` are the types of the "*three parameters*". But strictly speaking, that is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

To think of this from a more common view where functions can have multiple parameters, the last type in the signature is the return type. Everything before it is the types of the parameters.

In this example, your parameter types are `(a -> b -> b)`, `b`, and `[a]`: a function taking an `a` and a `b` and returning a `b`, a `b`, and a list of `a`s.

The return type is the last type in the signature `[b]`: a list of `b`s.

Answer (score 4):

Read type signatures as a transformation `... -> to`, where the "rest in the middle" are the arguments.

eg. `myscanr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]` "takes" a function `(a -> b -> b)`, a `b`, a list of a `[a]` and returns you a list of b `[b]`